# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Request failed with status code 404)

Tags: reactjs

found: Error: Request failed with status code 404

how to solve it.
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Please append the related code

Comment: The main issue here is `404`. Check why you are getting a `404`